# C++ class template specialization with value template parameters - how to prefer one over another?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, ambiguous, specialization

I have the following code:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct combine;

template<template<typename...> typename Tpl, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct combine< Tpl<Ts...>, Tpl<Us...> >
{
    using type = Tpl<Ts..., Us...>;
};

template<size_t Ind, size_t Curr, typename Tpl>
struct pack_upto_impl;

// SPECIALIZATION 1
template<size_t Matched, template<typename...> typename Tpl, typename... Ts>
struct pack_upto_impl<Matched, Matched, Tpl<Ts...> >
{
    using type = Tpl<>;
};

// SPECIALIZATION 2
template<size_t Ind, size_t Curr, template<typename...> typename Tpl, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct pack_upto_impl<Ind, Curr, Tpl<T, Ts...> >
{
    using remaining_type = typename pack_upto_impl<Ind, Curr+1, Tpl<Ts...>>::type;
    using type = typename combine<Tpl<T>, remaining_type>::type;
};

template<size_t Ind, typename Tpl>
using pack_upto = pack_upto_impl<Ind, 0, Tpl >;
```

What I want this to do is something like...

```
using T = tuple<int, double, short, float>;
pack_upto<0, T> var1; // this is tuple<>
pack_upto<1, T> var2; // this is tuple<int>
pack_upto<2, T> var3; // this is tuple<int, double>
...
```

When I try to do this, I get an error about ambiguous template specialization - when the first two template parameters of `pack_upto_impl` are the same, the compiler doesn't get the hint that I want SPECIALIZATION 1 rather than SPECIALIZATION 2.

What's the most elegant way of making this work?

Comment: With make_index_sequence, you can do it without writing a recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, some typos:

- The `, bool` in your definition of `remaining_type` needs to be removed.
- You probably wanted to write `using pack_upto = pack_upto_impl<Ind, 0, Tpl >::type;`. (Before C++20, you also need `typename` here.)

The core issue here is that you want specialization 1 to be considered "more specialized" than specialization 2 so that if a set of template arguments could match either specialization, specialization 1 is chosen. As you have currently written them, specialization 1 is not more specialized than specialization 2.

In order for specialization 1 to be more specialized than specialization 2, it must be the case that you could supply arbitrary values of the template arguments for specialization 1 and have the result match specialization 2 (*i.e.*, the template arguments of specialization 2 could be successfully deduced from anything you could instantiate from specialization 1). At present that condition is not met, because if `Ts...` is empty in specialization 1, it won't match specialization 2, which only accepts `Tpl<T, Ts...>` (*i.e.* `Tpl` must have at least 1 argument, not 0).

We can fix this by adding an extra specialization; call it specialization 3:

```
template<size_t Matched, template<typename...> typename Tpl, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct pack_upto_impl<Matched, Matched, Tpl<T, Ts...> >
{
    using type = Tpl<>;
};
```

So in this case, when we have a nonempty argument list to `Tpl`, this specialization will be chosen because it is more specialized than specialization 2. (When the argument list is empty, only specialization 1 matches in the first place, and there's no ambiguity.)

See the complete example [here on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8fbMzjadh).